# Avoiding Code Analysis CA1800 error in lambda expressions due to redundant casting

Tags: lambda, refactoring, expression, code-analysis

**Background**

I have an interface Interface1 which is inherited by Interface2, Interface 3...etc. Apart from Interface 1, all the other interfaces have concrete classes (object2,object3..etc) that implement their respective interfaces Interface 2, Interface 3...etc.

I also have a collection of objects of type Interface 1 where my intention is to populate with various objects.

**Problem**

I want to extract a particular object from this collection and am using lambda expression for it.

```
Object2 = IInterface1Collection.Single(item => item.GetType()==typeof(Object2)
            && ((Object2)item).Property1=="John" && ((Object2)item).Property2==0);
```

This code is giving Code Analysis Performance error of CA1800. It says

> Error  1   CA1800 : Microsoft.Performance : 'item', a parameter, is cast to type 'Object2' multiple times in method 'Method1()'. Cache the result of the 'as' operator or direct cast in order to eliminate the redundant castclass instruction.

If I suppress the message, it works fine and gets me the Object2 fulfilling the conditions.

**Question**

How can I avoid this error message? I have to cast item to Object2 as otherwise I cannot reach its properties. I cannot afford to create a collection of Object2 instead.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using `OfType` first:

```
Object2 = IInterface1Collection.OfType<Object2>()
                               .Single(item => item.Property1 == "John" && 
                                               item.Property2 == 0);
```

Note that this will behave *slightly* differently in that it will also include instances of *subclasses* of `Object2`. Is that a problem? If so, you can always write:

```
Object2 = IInterface1Collection.OfType<Object2>()
                               .Single(item => item.GetType() == typeof(Object2))
                                               item.Property1 == "John" && 
                                               item.Property2 == 0);
```

Comment: Awesome Jon! There are no subclasses of Object2. I will give this a try.